# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-visualization, reportviewer

I am working over Asp.Net MVC application. I am using report viewer. Everything was working good at development computer, when I uploaded this to my shared hosting, it started to throw this error.

I googled it, but I didn't found specific question to 'DataVisualization' dll, either I found similar questions like could not load ReportViewer.Webform etc.

Because I was getting error on 'DataVisualization.dll' file, so none of the solution worked for me.

Comment: That's probably not the full error message. Always post the full error message on SO

Comment: @CaiusJard Okay sir,

Answer (score 0):

Go to web config and delete or comment the following tag.

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization" publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This would only work if the server didn't have that exact version of the DLL installed, in which case the error would have been something like "the located assembly version doesn't match the required". Always post the full error message on SO